# Better way to clean product description using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-3.6

I have written following code to fetch product description from a site using BeautifulSoup-

```
def get_soup(url):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            html = response.content
            return BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    except Exception as ex:
        print("error from " + url + ": " + str(ex))

def get_product_details(url):
    try:
        soup = get_soup(url)
        prod_details = dict()
        desc_list = soup.select('p ~ ul')
        prod_details['description'] = ''.join(desc_list)
        return prod_details
    except Exception as ex:
        logger.warning('%s - %s', ex, url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_product_details("http://www.aprisin.com.sg/p-748-littletikespoptunesguitar.html")
```

In above code I am trying to convert description(a list) to string but getting below issue-

```
[WARNING] aprisin.py:82 get_product_details() : sequence item 0: expected str instance, Tag found - http://www.aprisin.com.sg/p-748-littletikespoptunesguitar.html
```

Output of description without converting description to string-

```
[<ul>
<li>Freestyle</li>
<li>Play along with 5 pre-set tunes: </li>
</ul>, <ul>
<li>Each string will play a note</li>
<li>Guitar has a whammy bar</li>
<li>2-in-1 volume control and power button </li>
<li>Simple and easy to use </li>
<li>Helps develop music appreciation </li>
<li>Requires 3 "AA" alkaline batteries (included)</li>
</ul>]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to join a list of Tags, but the join method needs str arguments. Try:

```
''.join([str(i) for i in desc_list])
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a list of `tags` (Object) instead of string to `join()`. `join()` works with list of strings. Use the following code changes for join function:-

```
prod_details['description'] = ''.join([tag.get_text() for tag in desc_list])
```

or

```
prod_details['description'] = ''.join([tag.string for tag in desc_list])
```

In case you want the description along with html content, you can use the following:-

```
# this will preserve the html tags and indentation.
prod_details['description'] = ''.join([tag.prettify() for tag in desc_list])
```

or

```
# this will return the html content as string.
prod_details['description'] = ''.join([str(tag) for tag in desc_list])
```

Comment: Thanks @nandlal I will use this.

Answer (score 1):

`desc_list` is list of `bs4.element.Tag`. you should convert tag to string:

```
    desc_list = soup.select('p ~ ul')
    prod_details['description'] = str(desc_list[0])
```

Comment: but this will remove html tags from the description and I don't want to exclude them

Comment: If you see the product url I am using above, description is in ul and li tag so I want to fetch complete description with tags.

Comment: i get `{'description': '<ul>\n<li>Freestyle</li>\n<li>Play along with 5 pre-set tunes:\xa0</li>\n</ul>'}` It seems perfect.

Comment: it is removing second element of ul-<ul>
<li>Freestyle</li>
<li>Play along with 5 pre-set tunes: </li>
</ul>